# Different <ul> don't stand under eachother

Tags: html, css, list, css-float, html-lists

Hello ( sorta newbe here), I made a page where there are different lists and I need them to stay under eachother. I didn't use any floats so I think the lists should not float next to eachother? 
The different lists are necessary to have a clear view of the different groups. In this case, different types of footballplayers. Here's the link:

http://www.ostameerbeke.be/spelerskern.html

```
        <h2>Keepers</h2>
        <ul id="keepers">          
            <li><a href="DE BACKER Glenn.JPG" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="DE BACKER Glenn.JPG" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p>DE BACKER</p> <p>Glenn</p></li>
            <li><a href="VERPAELST_Jeroen.JPG" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="VERPAELST_Jeroen.JPG" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p>VERPAELST</p> <p>Jeroen</p></li>
       </ul> 

       <h2>Verdedigers</h2> 
       <ul id="verdedigers">          
            <li><a href="9.JPG" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="9.JPG" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p>VAN LONDERSEELE</p> <p>Bram</p></li>
            <li><a href="DU MONGH Kim.JPG" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="DU MONGH Kim.JPG" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p>DUMONGH</p> <p>Kim</p></li>           
       </ul>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

CSS:

```
#keepers {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#keepers li { 
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#verdedigers {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#verdedigers li { 
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code as part of your question.

Comment: @RachelGallen, bear in mind `dear` can be considered condescending - don't think you mean it like that, though

Comment: @RAchel, the footballpalyer page I guess... :D I don't see any list in the site....

Comment: Looking at the source code of the site there are the <ul> but they do not show in the page at all. if Rachel Gallen suggestion of ul{display:block;} does not work, place an ungly <br clear="both">.

Comment: Add this css property to h2 {float: left; width: 90%;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this into your code here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u140hpyL/1/)

```
ul#trainers, ul#keepers, ul#verdedigers, ul#middenvelders, ul#aanvallers
        {display:block!important; max-width:1000px; overflow-x:auto;}
```

Comment: you have to add it into your style sheet

Comment: did you add the FULL LINE of code to your css? put it after the body css

Comment: Your code works fine :) I uploaded the page on another server and it does the trick. I also had troubles with something else on my server but when I uploaded it on another server, it worked perfectly. So I think I have a problem with my server... Is it possible that a page works on one server but not on another?

Comment: @vanberla strange, but stranger things have happened!!! html is weird i think... :)

Comment: there was a problem with my caching. The server always uploaded an older version so I couldn't see changes I made. Now it's (hopefully) fixed by refreshing with CTRL + F5 :)

Comment: Aha! Always a reason :)